# sload. assembly with struct - not working in solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, assembly

```js
struct S { 
   uint128 a; 
   uint128 b; 
}
S test1;
function assemblyStorage() public returns (uint a, uint b, uint c, uint d, uint f, uint g){
  test1 = S(5,10);
  assembly {
     a:=sload(0)
  }
}
```

As we can see, `test1` now will occupy the first slot. and not the second one since variables can be packed...

Now, why does `sload(0)` returns something like this `3402823669209384634633746074317682114565` and how can I return 5 and 10 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said the struct is packed. Since `sload(0)` returns 32 bytes it is returning the whole struct.

To access the indiviual parts of the struct use bit shifts and masks.

```
assembly {
    let w := sload(0)
    a := and(w, 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff)
    b := shr(128, w)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ismael. Could you take a look at this too ? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87988/where-does-function-variables-get-created/87989

Comment: What if struct contains c,d,e,f,g,h ?

Comment: @normal_human If all are uint128 then you have to read c & d from the 1 slot, e & f from the 2 slot, etc.