# sload. with struct - loading bytes

Tags: struct, assembly, bytes

I'm trying to load varios bytes from a struct in assembly. I found a good [explanation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87975/sload-assembly-with-struct-not-working-in-solidity) here for uint. While this is working for uint and the whole memory slot i cant figure out how to get a bytes1 or bytes12 variable from the struct.

```
contract Storage {

mapping(uint256 => turmite) public turmites;

struct turmite {
    bytes1 state;
    bytes12 baserule;
}

bytes1 state = hex"02";
constructor(){
    turmites[1] = turmite(
    state,
    0xff0801ff0201ff0000000001
    );
}

function retrieve(uint id) public{
    turmite storage data = turmites[id];
    bytes12 b;
    bytes1 a;
    bytes32 completeslot;
    assembly {
        let w := sload(data.slot)
        completeslot := w
        a := and(w, 0xff)
}   
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bytes & Strings are left aligned, while numbers (*i.e.,* uintX) are right aligned.

- bytes32(bytes1(0xFF)) -> 0xFF0...00
- uint256(uint8(0xFF)) -> 0x00...0FF

Leading to such behavior :

```
function test() public view returns (bytes1) {
    uint256 value = 0xFF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
    bytes1 rvalue;

    assembly {
        rvalue := value
    }

    return rvalue; // 0xFF
}
```

SLOAD returns a uint256, when trying to put this value in a bytes1 you are actually getting the 32th byte of the uint (Throughout this answer, byte 32 is far left, byte 0 is far right), not the 1st. With bytes12, you get the range 32 to 20 instead of 12 to 0.

This is exactly what happens with :

```
// clears bytes 32 to 1 and puts byte 32 into a
// because a is byte1 : left aligned
a := and(w, 0xff)
```

You could work directly on ints and only convert before returning outside the assembly block like so :

```
function retrieve(uint id) public view returns (bytes1, bytes12) {
        turmite storage data = turmites[id];
        uint96 b;
        uint8 a;

        assembly {
                let w := sload(data.slot)
                a := w
                b := shr(8, w)
        }

        return (bytes1(a), bytes12(b));   
}
```

Or stick with bytesX and shift your values **left** as this is where they will be picked up :

```
  function retrieve(uint id) public view returns (bytes1, bytes12) {
        turmite storage data = turmites[id];
        bytes12 b;
        bytes1 a;

        assembly {
                let w := sload(data.slot)

                // Shift 152 bits (19 bytes) left to bring data.baserule at byte 32
                b := shl(152, w)

                // shift 248 bits (31 bytes) left to bring data.state at byte 32
                a := shl(248, w)
        }

        return (a, b);  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the summary - really helpfull!